# Receiving the Event.COPY event in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, keyboard-shortcuts, flash, copy-paste

My goal is to know when a user presses the cut, copy, paste, or select all keyboard shortcuts and do some processing for each one. I tried listening for the keypresses, but only some keys are fired when the control key is down (apparently it would work only in the browser, except for IE).

Then I was reading the Flash docs and came across the [Event.COPY](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event:copy), [Event.PASTE](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event:paste), and [Event.CUT](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event:cut) events that are dispatched to the "object that currently has focus". I attached listeners to the document class for these events and set stage.focus to the document class, but my event listeners never get called.

Has anyone used these events? Is there an example somewhere on how to use them?

Note: This is in Flash Player 10 (both the internal CS4 one (with "Disable Shortcuts" checked off) and the stand-alone one). I have not tried it in any browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside the restriction of not beeing able to capture such events from TextFields (or when the focus is on a TextField), make sure that the stage.focus property is indeed set to the InteractiveObject you attached the listeners to, or any of its childs (unless its a textfield ^^).

Bear in mind that you can only set the focus by directly setting the stage.focus property, and by clicking or tabbing on tabEnabled InteractiveObjects.

Comment: You're right -- as it turns out I did set stage.focus, but because of circumstances unique to my application (I had to click on a certain area before doing anything), the focus changed and my events would never be heard from again. I fixed this with a (very) crude but effective solution: I listen for the focusOut event, and then set stage.focus to my InteractiveObject that has the event listeners. I'll have to figure something else out later though, because this probably won't work when I have dynamic TextFields :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness' sake, here's the class I ended up using to allow the focus to go to a few objects on a "white-list", then revert the focus to a default object when the focus is lost from the white-list object (unless it's going to another white-list object):

```
/*
Copyright (c) 2009, Cameron Desrochers
All rights reserved.

Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification, are permitted
provided that the following conditions are met:

    * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this list of
      conditions and the following disclaimer.
    * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list
      of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials
      provided with the distribution.

THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND 
ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED 
WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE 
DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR 
ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES 
(INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; 
LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON 
ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT 
(INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS 
SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
*/


package
{
    import fl.controls.ColorPicker;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.InteractiveObject;
    import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.FocusEvent;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import flash.utils.Dictionary;



    public class FocusManager
    {
        public static var stage:Stage;
        public static var defaultFocalObject:DisplayObjectContainer;

        private static var _whiteList:Array = new Array();


        public static function init(stage:Stage, defaultFocalObject:DisplayObjectContainer):void
        {
            FocusManager.stage = stage;
            FocusManager.defaultFocalObject = defaultFocalObject;

            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onStageClicked);

            defaultFocalObject.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_OUT, onObjectFocusOut);

            restoreDefaultFocus();
        }


        public static function restoreDefaultFocus():void
        {
            stage.focus = defaultFocalObject;
        }


        public static function addToWhiteList(object:InteractiveObject):void
        {
            if (Object(object).constructor == ColorPicker) {        // Special case
                // ColorPicker objects possess a textField that is for some reason not a child of the
                // ColorPicker, and so the textField has to be added separately.

                addToWhiteList(ColorPicker(object).textField);
            }

            _whiteList.push(object);

            object.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_OUT, onObjectFocusOut);
            object.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, onObjectRemovedFromStage);
        }


        private static function onObjectFocusOut(e:FocusEvent):void
        {
            //trace('e.target:', e.target);
            //trace('e.relatedObject:', e.relatedObject);

            if ((e.relatedObject == null) || ((e.relatedObject !== defaultFocalObject) && (!whiteListContains(e.relatedObject)))) {
                // Object that is gaining focus is not in white-list, restore focus:

                //trace('restoring default focus');
                restoreDefaultFocus();
            }
        }


        private static function whiteListContains(object):Boolean
        {
            var inList:Boolean = false;

            for each (var listItem in _whiteList) {
                if ((object === listItem) || ((listItem.hasOwnProperty('contains')) && (listItem.contains(object)))) {
                    inList = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return inList;
        }


        private static function onObjectRemovedFromStage(e:Event):void
        {
            restoreDefaultFocus();
        }


        private static function onStageClicked(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var objectsUnderClick:Array = stage.getObjectsUnderPoint(new Point(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY));

            var clickedOnWhiteListItem:Boolean = false;
            for each (var object in objectsUnderClick) {
                if (whiteListContains(object)) {
                    clickedOnWhiteListItem = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!clickedOnWhiteListItem) {
                restoreDefaultFocus();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Call the static `init` method with the document class's `stage` object and the object that you'd like the focus to return to by default. Then add objects to the white-list with the static `addToWhitelist` method.